# show all Data from Permission Table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables like that:

```
PermissionsTbl
__________________
PermissionID            int         NotNull
PermissionDescription   nvarchar(100)   NotNull

PermissionID      PermissionDescription 
1             Human Resources
2             Employees Data
3             Departements

ActivePermissionsTbl
________________________
ActivePermID    bigint  NotNull
PermissionID    int NotNull
UserID          int NotNull
PageActive  bit NotNull

ActivePermID    PermissionID    UserID     PageActive        
1           1           1      True
2           2           1      True
3           3           2      True
```

what I want is show data like that:

```
PermissionID      PermissionDescription   PageActive     UserID               
1                 Human Resources         True           1
2                 Employees Data          True           1
3                 Departements                           1
1                 Human Resources                        2
2                 Employees Data                         2
3                 Departements            True           2
```

I try several methods of Join , but I failed< any suggestion please.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure someone can find a more elegant/efficient solution, but this appears to give you what you need:

```
SELECT
    a.PermissionID ,
    A.PermissionDescription ,
    ISNULL(ap.PageActive , 0) 'PageActive' ,
    a.UserID
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        *
    FROM permissionstbl p
    CROSS JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            userid
        FROM activepermissionstbl
    )
    a
)
a
LEFT JOIN activepermissionstbl ap ON ap.userid = a.userid AND ap.permissionid = a.permissionid
ORDER BY a.userid
```

So the inner query gets the Cartesian product of the two tables and then distincts them. Then for each one of those results it gets the appropriate permission in the active permissions table.

Using a left join for this so that any null results means they don't currently have an activepermission and thus the pageactive value is false.

[View Demo Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f3ec2/21/0)